# ag-grid : setting rowHeight manually

Tags: angular, angular8, ag-grid

I am trying to set the row height of ag-grid like below

```
<ag-grid-angular  style="height: 130px;"  [rowData]="rows"  [columnDefs]="columns" [getRowHeight]="getRowHeight">
```

and in ts file

```
getRowHeight = 5;
```

I also changed it to 5px but it is not reflecting. any other way to do the same.

I am doing it in angular8

I also added the snapshot it looks like after I made it 20px
[image]

Answer (score 2):

`getRowHeight` is the callback function but why can't you just use the property `rowHeight` on the grid object itself. Like this:

```
<ag-grid-angular  style="height: 130px;"  [rowData]="rows"  [columnDefs]="columns" [rowHeight]="rowHeight">
```

And then in your component:

`rowHeight = 5`

**Edit 1:**

You can also set autoheight for your rows - then the row height will be adapted according to the provided data:

In your template: `<ag-grid-angular [defaultColDef]="defaultColDef" ...(all the other options)... >`
In your component:

```
this.defaultColDef = {
      flex: 1,
      autoHeight: true,
};
```

The default value is 25 (pixels)

Comment: yes this one is working, but the data is not coming in the center of the row. anything else we can do for it ?

Comment: @sparsh610 do you mean in the center of the row vertically or horizontally?

Comment: I mean vertically

Comment: Can you provide a stackblitz demonstrating the problem? And could it be that 5 pixels is just not enought to cover the content?

Comment: I made it 20, as the data is dynamic so I cannot demonstrate that.

Comment: added the screenshot to refer

Comment: @sparsh610 see my edit with regard to autoheight. Is this what you are looking for?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/214852/discussion-between-sparsh610-and-anton).